# C#, Npgsql, NpgsqlCommandBuilder and transferred data

Tags: c#, npgsql

I am developing a C# app that connects to a remote Postgresql database.
The database size is ~50-60Mb (this is approximately the size of the "data\base" folder and the size returned by "select pg_database_size"), but if I perform a "SELECT * FROM " on all tables, the data trasferred through the LAN is ~600Mb (ten time bigger!).

I checked that most of data trasfer is due to CommandBuilder

```
NpgsqlCommandBuilder cBuilder = new NpgsqlCommandBuilder(_dAdapter);
_dAdapter.DeleteCommand = cBuilder.GetDeleteCommand();
_dAdapter.InsertCommand = cBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
_dAdapter.UpdateCommand = cBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
```

Where is the issue? There is a way to minimize the data transfer performing a "SELECT *" query?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with C# and very little to do with Npgsql.

What it has to do with is not comparing like with like.

On the one hand you have the database's internal storage. This is data on disk stored in a way designed with a primary goal of quick querying and updating, along with a goal of taking up little disk space when possible. In particular, all large values stored using TOAST is compressed internally.

See the documentation on [Database Physical Storage](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/storage.html) for more.

This you say is about 50-60 Mb (though I guess you probably mean MB) in your case.

On the other hand you have the database's Frontend/Backend Protocol, which is how postgresql servers and clients communicate with each other.

While reducing the number of bytes involved is also a goal here, so too is ease of translation for the applications involved. The problems around representing the boundaries between different values is completely different, and there is also SSL overhead and so on if you are going over a wire.

See the documentation on [Frontend/Backend Protocol](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/protocol.html) for more.

As such while some of what is stored in the files is irrelevant here, we would expect the size of a full transfer to be much, much larger. You say 600Mb (again, I'm guessing you mean MB), so that matches that.

> Where is the issue?

There is no issue.

> There is a way to minimize the data transfer performing a "SELECT *" query?

Well, one will hopefully be coming for free in a bit, as the Npgsql team were working on some reductions to transfer size through more optimised use of the protocol last time I checked. (I contributed to Npgsql some years ago, but these days I only occasionally have a look at what they're up to).

This optimisation will be worth doing, along with other optimisation work, but it's still not going to make a big difference though: Even if you hand-optimised all the Frontend/Backend protocol uses (and even if you did so with the advantage of prior knowledge of the actual data allowing you to make the perfect choice in cases where one approach results in smaller transfers sometimes and larger other times) there's still going to be a much greater size for doing `SELECT *` on all tables than the size involved in storage.*

Beyond that, the best way to reduce the cost of doing `SELECT *` are not to do so:

1. Avoid grabbing entire tables in the first place; engineer as much as possible to select only meaningful data to a given use.
2. If you really need to grab everything, use `COPY`. This postgresql extension to SQL is supported by Npgsql and is optimised for bulk transfer rather than queries.

Using `COPY` may or may not be meaningfully smaller, so it's worth seeing how it fairs with your particular set of data.

*Just how much larger would depend on how much space was taken up by indices, how much saved by the database containing large values that were compressed in TOAST and as such there could potentially be a case where transfer size was in fact smaller than storage size, but that would be a side-effect of the data stored rather than something one could deliberately engineer for.

Comment: Thank you Jon Hanna, now things are clearer. What I can't still understand is why getting Insert/Update/Delete commands from NpgsqlCommandBuilder transfers about half of the total data (it sounds to me like if all data is trasferred twice, one for commandBuilder activity and one to fill DataAdapter with data). Finally I add a detail: the reason I need to SELECT * data is that I need the remote copy of the data to sync local tables containing the same data (maybe it would be best to ask a long time ago what is the better way to do this).

Comment: COPY is certainly useful for blind syncs, though much better still (but more work upfront) is delta-syncing where you can work out just what rows have changed and update only what is new.

Comment: The reason why I decided for a trivial "SELECT *" is that I don't know how to manage deleted row (both in local or remote db) with delta-sync. Anyway this is offtopic here. And I still have doubts about the CommandBuilder behavior!